# What bandwidth is needed for an arbitrary digital signal?

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications, bandwidth, optoelectronics, digital-modulation

I am building a fiber-optic data link, with a laser driver and photodiode receiver.  My goal is to transmit data at 50Mbit/s.  I'm looking for what bandwidth this would take.
Obviously 50MHz would not work, as it would not even begin to approximate a square wave, let alone change in random data periodicity, right?
How many harmonics do I need?  We have designed so that our low frequency cutoff is sufficiently low compared to our data rate (by ~5 orders of magnitude).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the principles of baseband data transmission, which is used by ethernet. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_code . Also, please tell us more about your problem. What distance, why this data rate, cost?

Comment: In the fiber optics datacom world, we use a rule of thumb that roughly A/2 Hz bandwidth is required to support a data rate of A bps with on-off-keying (OOK). So 25 MHz would be sufficient to support 50 Mbps transmission. However, slightly more bandwidth is generally better, and we typically define a reference receiver for transmitter characterization with 0.75 A Hz bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At full data rate, you have a square wave that is 25 MHz and if you have a 3dB bandwidth of 75 MHz you'll pass the 3rd harmonic through without too much loss of shape. It won't look perfect but the eye pattern will be good enough. Below shows how the square wave is "built" from its harmonics. The picture after the sinewave at the fundamental is the "square wave that only contains the 3rd harmonic and, hopefull you can see that it is still fairly reasonable in shape: -

[image]

Eye patterns for data that has been restricted in bandwidth are also a useful source of information. For instance the one below pretty much looks like data that contains very few harmonics: -

[image]

The above informs anyone who knows about data transmission systems that the eye pattern shape is pretty good and easily converted back to proper logic levels - it's the amount of white space (surronded by the red traces) that gives confidence here. Maybe you should study eye diagrams.

You can also use tools like LTSpice for simulating data that has been bandlimited in order to figure out detection regimes that will work. You have to contend with noise, poor rise (and fall) times, small amplitudes and inter-symbol distortion. It's do-able.

You can buy off the shelf solutions that are good for at least 4 times your data rate and don't cost the earth. I have built links that are good for 700 Mbps that use 1 GHz bandwidth optics so that should set some form of benchmark for you.

Comment: Great answer here. Do you mean a 3dB cutoff of 75MHz so that the channel only passes the 1st and 3rd harmonics? This would mean a bandwidth of 75 - 25 = 50MHz, right?

Comment: A 3dB cut at 75 MHz is at the 3rd harmonic i.e. slightly attenuating it. At 125 MHz the fifth harmonic will still pass but significantly attenuated. How much depends on the laser, photodiode and the electronics at both ends but asssuming it is all equivalent to a 1st order low pass filter, 125 MHz (fifth harmonic) will be attenuated by about another 3 dB.